# Load CSV files one by one into Excel VBA Userform

Tags: excel, vba, csv, userform

I am trying to load some csv files from a folder to show its contents in a Userform, currently my code looks like this:

```
Private Sub btnGetData_Click()
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    
    Dim iIndex      As Integer
    Dim ws          As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim wb          As Workbook
    Dim strPath     As String
    Dim strFile     As String
    
'    Find .csv files in folder
    strPath = "C:\mycsvfiles\"
    strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.csv")
    
    Do While strFile <> ""
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=strPath & strFile, Local:=True)
        
        For iIndex = 1 To wb.Worksheets.Count
            Set ws = wb.Worksheets(iIndex)
            
'            Populate UserForm
            Me.textbox1.value = Trim(wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A2").value)
            Me.textbox2.value = Trim(wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A4").value)
            Me.textbox3.value = Trim(wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A6").value)
            Me.textbox4.value = Trim(wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A8").value)
            Me.textbox5.value = Trim(wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A9").value)
            Me.textbox6.value = Trim(wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A11").value) & ", " & Trim(wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A12").value)
            
'            Close csv file
            Workbooks(strFile).Close SaveChanges:=False

        Next iIndex
        strFile = Dir        'This moves the value of strFile to the next file.

    Loop
    
End Sub
```

So, when clicking button "btnGetData" all CSV files are found. When the loop ends, the fields in userform are populated with the last file found.

What I need is to load the files one by one while interacting with a previous and next file buttons like this:

```
Private Sub btn_NEXT_Click()
'        Read content of next csv file found
End Sub

Private Sub btn_PREV_Click()
'        Read content of previous csv file found
End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

Based on Brian M Stafford reply, I post the code that came up as solution to my problem, hopefully it can be of help to someone else.

```
Private Sub btnGetData_Click()
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    '   Create collection of files
    Dim f As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    f = Dir("C:\somefolder\*.csv")
    Set MyFiles = New Collection
    Do While f <> ""
        MyFiles.Add "C:\somefolder\" & f
        f = Dir
    Loop
    '   Set Index
    CurrentIndex = 1
    '   Open Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=MyFiles(CurrentIndex), Local:=True)
    '   Populate UserForm
    Me.textbox1.value = Trim(wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A2").value)
    Me.textbox2 = Trim(wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A4").value)
    Me.textbox3.value = Trim(wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A6").value)
    Me.textbox4.value = Trim(wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A8").value)
    Me.textbox4.value = Trim(wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A9").value)
    '   Close Workbook
    wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    
End Sub


Private Sub btn_NEXT_Click()
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    '   Set Index
    CurrentIndex = CurrentIndex + 1
    If CurrentIndex > MyFiles.Count Then CurrentIndex = MyFiles.Count
    '   Open Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=MyFiles(CurrentIndex), Local:=True)
    '   Populate UserForm
    Me.textbox1.value = Trim(wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A2").value)
    Me.textbox2 = Trim(wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A4").value)
    Me.textbox3.value = Trim(wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A6").value)
    Me.textbox4.value = Trim(wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A8").value)
    Me.textbox4.value = Trim(wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A9").value)
    '   Close Workbook
    wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    
End Sub

Private Sub btn_PREV_Click()
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    '   Set Index
    CurrentIndex = CurrentIndex - 1
    If CurrentIndex < 1 Then CurrentIndex = 1
    '   Open Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=MyFiles(CurrentIndex), Local:=True)
    '   Populate UserForm
    Me.textbox1.value = Trim(wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A2").value)
    Me.textbox2 = Trim(wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A4").value)
    Me.textbox3.value = Trim(wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A6").value)
    Me.textbox4.value = Trim(wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A8").value)
    Me.textbox4.value = Trim(wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A9").value)
    '   Close Workbook
    wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The challenge is maintaining an index into the files in your folder.  Neither `Dir` nor `FileSystemObject` allow you to access files by index.  One way to accomplish this is to place the files into a Collection which does allow access by index.  I stripped the code down to illustrate this idea:

```
Option Explicit

Private MyFiles As Collection
Private CurrentIndex As Integer

Private Sub btnGetData_Click()
   Dim f As String
   
   f = Dir("c:\temp\csv\*.csv")
   Set MyFiles = New Collection
   
   Do While f <> ""
      MyFiles.Add "c:\temp\csv\" & f
      f = Dir
   Loop
   
   CurrentIndex = 1
   Label1.Caption = MyFiles(CurrentIndex)
End Sub

Private Sub btnNext_Click()
   CurrentIndex = CurrentIndex + 1
   If CurrentIndex > MyFiles.Count Then CurrentIndex = MyFiles.Count
   Label1.Caption = MyFiles(CurrentIndex)
End Sub

Private Sub btnPrevious_Click()
   CurrentIndex = CurrentIndex - 1
   If CurrentIndex < 1 Then CurrentIndex = 1
   Label1.Caption = MyFiles(CurrentIndex)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Brian, I was testing the code and it works as expected but I didn't know how to access the file to pull the data and place it in the corresponding fields in the userform, I've tried like this:
   Me.textbox1.value = Trim(MyFiles(1).Worksheets(1).Range("A2").value) but it´s not working.

Comment: It's going to be like you had before:  load the csv into a workbook and go from there.  So in your case start with `Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=MyFiles(CurrentIndex), Local:=True)`.

Comment: Yes Brian, I've figured it out last night, I've edited the original post and select your answer as correct, thank you for your helpful insights.